# Evaluate a string in a MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that I would like to pass a string to, to be evaluated in the query.
I will be building a string in php, based on query parameters that exist.
So, my string might be `col1 = val1` or `col1 = val1 AND col2 = val2 AND col3 = val3`, ect.
Then in my stored procedure, I would do something like this:
`SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * from tablename WHERE ' , string);
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;`
I have tried some different ways of doing this, with no success.
Is this possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code it valid, you might have an error though.
Try debugging it by replacing 
PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt;

with

SELECT @s;

then make sure the output is valid by running it, its possible your building @s incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your entire proc, that does seem like something that should work.  Make sure you specify 'READS SQL DATA' in the CREATE clause for your stored proc, ie:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `foo`(IN bar varchar(100))
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
-- blah blah blah
END
```

I'm doing what you are trying to do in MySQL, so you're just missing some little thing somewhere.